# Yarn module not found error in azure pipelines via cache mechanism

Tags: caching, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, hadoop-yarn, pipeline

thank you in advance for looking at this issue for me.

Am working on improving our CI build times in azure devops pipelines via [this caching mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#nodejsyarn) that is offered. Am also using the [cache restored boolean function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/caching?view=azure-devops#conditioning-on-cache-restoration) mentioned in the link.

The summary of the steps are as per screenshot below[image]

**Summary of Steps**

1. Check cache for yarn packages.
2. Retrieve packages from cache if there is a cache hit
3. Skip the yarn install step which pulls packages from public source and takes some time if there is a cache hit.
4. Run yarn Build.

The issue appears specfically in the yarn build step where it complains about not being able to find a node_module as per below error log.

```
2020-10-12T21:28:00.1761207Z ##[section]Starting: yarn build
2020-10-12T21:28:00.1884736Z ==============================================================================
2020-10-12T21:28:00.1885119Z Task         : PowerShell
2020-10-12T21:28:00.1885475Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
2020-10-12T21:28:00.1885806Z Version      : 2.170.1
2020-10-12T21:28:00.1886094Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-10-12T21:28:00.1886495Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
2020-10-12T21:28:00.1886967Z ==============================================================================
2020-10-12T21:28:01.0882035Z Generating script.
2020-10-12T21:28:01.1294597Z ========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
2020-10-12T21:28:01.1574727Z ##[command]"C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\24379d8e-967c-4af6-9674-96aa85df30a4.ps1'"
2020-10-12T21:28:06.5140487Z yarn run v1.22.10
2020-10-12T21:28:06.5712118Z $ yarn run clean:builddir
2020-10-12T21:28:07.7032890Z $ npx rimraf ./Scripts/build
2020-10-12T21:28:31.4416409Z npx: installed 12 in 14.71s
2020-10-12T21:28:31.5265827Z $ npx concurrently --names "app,workspaces" "npx cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192 npx webpack --mode production" "yarn wsrun -m --parallel build:prod" --verbose
2020-10-12T21:28:43.6196644Z npx: installed 54 in 11.679s
2020-10-12T21:28:44.5023615Z [workspaces] error Command "wsrun" not found.
2020-10-12T21:28:44.5026888Z [workspaces] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2020-10-12T21:28:44.5030627Z [workspaces] yarn wsrun -m --parallel build:prod exited with code 1
2020-10-12T21:28:46.4240020Z [app] npx: installed 7 in 1.967s
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1434285Z [app] C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:93
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1435399Z [app]              throw err;
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1435915Z [app]              ^
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1436363Z [app] 
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1436924Z [app] Error: Cannot find module 'webpack-bundle-analyzer'
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1437490Z [app] Require stack:
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1438065Z [app] - D:\a\1\s\Abstracted.Web.App\webpack.config.js
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1438780Z [app] - C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1441594Z [app] - C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1442320Z [app] - C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1443090Z [app]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1443973Z [app]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1445082Z [app]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1446059Z [app]     at require (C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1447302Z [app]     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\a\1\s\Abstracted.Web.App\webpack.config.js:3:30)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1448348Z [app]     at Module._compile (C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1449351Z [app]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1450132Z [app]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1453332Z [app]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1454342Z [app]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1455342Z [app]     at require (C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1456524Z [app]     at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:114:13)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1457530Z [app]     at requireConfig (C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:116:6)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1460155Z [app]     at C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:123:17
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1460996Z [app]     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1461622Z [app]     at module.exports (C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\utils\convert-argv.js:121:15)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1462534Z [app]     at C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:71:45
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1463445Z [app]     at Object.parse (C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack-cli\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:576:18)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1464195Z [app]     at C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:49:8
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1465077Z [app]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:366:3)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1465949Z [app]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1467013Z [app]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1467607Z [app]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1468654Z [app]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1469217Z [app]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1469969Z [app]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1470800Z [app]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\npm\prefix\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js:156:2)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1471434Z [app]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1472287Z [app]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1473085Z [app]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32) {
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1473556Z [app]   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1474272Z [app]   requireStack: [
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1474736Z [app]     'D:\\a\\1\\s\\Abstracted.Web.App\\webpack.config.js',
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1475804Z [app]     'C:\\npm\\prefix\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\utils\\convert-argv.js',
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1476626Z [app]     'C:\\npm\\prefix\\node_modules\\webpack-cli\\bin\\cli.js',
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1477161Z [app]     'C:\\npm\\prefix\\node_modules\\webpack\\bin\\webpack.js'
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1477854Z [app]   ]
2020-10-12T21:29:09.1478179Z [app] }
2020-10-12T21:29:09.2871272Z [app] npx cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192 npx webpack --mode production exited with code 1
2020-10-12T21:29:11.8915556Z error Command failed with exit code 1.
2020-10-12T21:29:11.8918295Z info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
2020-10-12T21:29:12.1132424Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
2020-10-12T21:29:12.2192481Z ##[section]Finishing: yarn build
```

I have placed a debug step as per below results and can see that there is definitely a module restored with the name mentioned.

**Question**
I am wondering where the problem might be as I am not sure why the yarn build step is unable to see the cache module even though I set a value for `YARN_CACHE_FOLDER = $(Pipeline.Workspace)\.yarn` and I can see the build module in the debug.

Things I have tried.

- If I do not skip the yarn install step everything works fine.
- Have passed the yarn build command with input of `--cache-folder $(YARN_CACHE_FOLDER)`
- Have set `npm_config_cache` variable pointing to same location as yarn cache folder as I can see that yarn ultimately is `yarn --> npm --> npx`
- Have set `npm config set cache $(YARN_CACHE_FOLDER) --global`

**debug cache folder results**

```
2020-10-12T21:27:57.9564700Z ##[command]"C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\41464daa-068a-4419-b4ee-a22669f1d505.ps1'"
2020-10-12T21:27:58.2263973Z Yarn Cache Folder: D:\a\1\.yarn
2020-10-12T21:27:58.2878796Z 
2020-10-12T21:27:58.2879351Z 
2020-10-12T21:27:58.2882145Z     Directory: D:\a\1\.yarn
2020-10-12T21:27:58.2882732Z 
2020-10-12T21:27:58.2883036Z 
2020-10-12T21:27:58.2889439Z Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
2020-10-12T21:27:58.2892321Z ----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
2020-10-12T21:27:58.2897508Z d-----       10/12/2020   9:14 PM                v6                                                                    
2020-10-12T21:27:58.3052399Z 
2020-10-12T21:27:58.3052981Z 
2020-10-12T21:27:58.3053995Z     Directory: D:\a\1\.yarn\v6
2020-10-12T21:27:58.3054249Z 
2020-10-12T21:27:58.3054668Z 
2020-10-12T21:27:58.3059237Z Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
2020-10-12T21:27:58.3061399Z ----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
2020-10-12T21:27:58.3090817Z d-----       10/12/2020   9:13 PM                npm-webpack-bundle-analyzer-3.8.0-ce6b3f908daf069fd1f7266f692cbb3bded9
2020-10-12T21:27:58.3091604Z                                                  ba16-integrity                                                        
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0136005Z 
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0137465Z 
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0139239Z     Directory: 
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0140339Z     D:\a\1\.yarn\v6\npm-webpack-bundle-analyzer-3.8.0-ce6b3f908daf069fd1f7266f692cbb3bded9ba16-integrity\node_modules
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0141165Z 
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0142124Z 
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0145599Z Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0148653Z ----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0286731Z d-----       10/12/2020   9:13 PM                webpack-bundle-analyzer                                               
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0320519Z 
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0321138Z 
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0365021Z     Directory: D:\a\1\.yarn\v6\npm-webpack-bundle-analyzer-3.8.0-ce6b3f908daf069fd1f7266f692cbb3bded9ba16-integrity\nod
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0365533Z     e_modules\webpack-bundle-analyzer\.bin
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0365731Z 
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0365869Z 
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0370893Z Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0373787Z ----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0378379Z -a----       10/12/2020   9:13 PM            309 webpack-bundle-analyzer                                               
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0390041Z -a----       10/12/2020   9:13 PM            186 webpack-bundle-analyzer.cmd                                           
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0964047Z 
2020-10-12T21:28:00.0964303Z 
2020-10-12T21:28:00.1723744Z ##[section]Finishing: debug cache folder
```

**Abstracted YAML of Pipeline Definition**

```
variables:
  - name: System.Debug 
    value: false
  - name: YARN_CACHE_FOLDER
    value: $(Pipeline.Workspace)\.yarn
  - name: npm_config_cache 
    value: $(Pipeline.Workspace)\.yarn\v6

  
stages:
  # Build All Apps
- stage: Stage1
  displayName: Build
  condition: true
  jobs:
    
    - job: BuildCI
      condition: succeeded()
      steps:

      - checkout: self
        fetchDepth: 1
      - task: Cache@2
        displayName: Cache Yarn packages
        # condition: false
        inputs:
          key: 'yarn | "$(Agent.OS)" | CompanyName.Web.App\yarn.lock'
          restoreKeys: |
            yarn | "$(Agent.OS)"
          path: $(YARN_CACHE_FOLDER)
          cacheHitVar: CACHE_RESTORED

      - powershell: |
          Write-Host "Yarn Cache Folder: $(YARN_CACHE_FOLDER)"
          Write-Host "Searching Pipeline.Workspace Folder for WebPack"
          gci $(Pipeline.Workspace) -filter "*webpack-bundle-analyzer*" -recurse | Select FullName
        #condition: false
        displayName: 'debug folder'
  
      - task: Yarn@2
        displayName: 'Yarn Install Web.App'
        # condition: succeeded()
        condition: |
          and
          (
            succeeded(),
            ne(variables.CACHE_RESTORED, 'false')
          )
        inputs:
          ProjectDirectory: 'CompanyName.Web.App'
          Arguments: '--network-timeout 100000'
      
      - powershell: |
          Write-Host "Yarn Cache Folder: $(YARN_CACHE_FOLDER)"
          Write-Host "Searching Pipeline.Workspace Folder for WebPack"
          gci $(Pipeline.Workspace) -filter "*webpack-bundle-analyzer*" -recurse | Select FullName
        #condition: false
        displayName: 'debug folder'

      - powershell: |
          yarn --cwd "CompanyName.Web.App" build:prod --verbose
        displayName: 'yarn build'
```

Comment: From your debug step, the module has been installed in the `D:\a\1\.yarn folder`. But from the error log,  It does not seem to use the packages under this folder. When you use the yarn install, please check the location of the packages(yarn install). Please share the Pipeline definition with us.

Comment: hi @KevinLu-MSFT I have added the `yaml` definition to the original post, too long for comment.

Yea the package definitely is being pulled but not sure why `yarn install` is not pulling it.

Comment: From the yaml sample, it seems that the package will be downloaded to `.yarn` folder. But from your debug step, the packages are downloaded to `xxx/.yarn/v6`. You could try to create a new pipeline and set it to cache the package to `xx/.yarn` folder. Please check if it could make some changes.

Comment: @Sl-NZ did you resolve this issue? I am facing a similar issue now.

Comment: @walkerrandophsmith no we did not, I believe that the yarn install step does more then pull packages based on what we I learnt about yarn, it actually links yarn packages together when we dug into it further and the yarn build does not do this so pulling from cache not enough.

Comment: @Sl-NZ Thanks for the response. I worked through my issue today and posted an answer below. You may have moved on from this problem, but hopefully this solves your issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the directory I needed to cache was not the global yarn modules, but instead my project's `node_modules`. I updated my yml pipeline to include

```
variables:
  YARN_CACHE_FOLDER: myproject\node_modules
```